# Linking two nodes together if both are connected to three other nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with two types of nodes: people nodes and products purchased, with the relationships being a purchase. I want to link two people nodes together if the two nodes share three product nodes, i.e if they have purchased three of the same things. What is the best way to go about doing this?

The graph has a few hundred million nodes. Which way will be the fastest also? In cypher I was thinking maybe something like the following, but it's taking ages and seems to be doing nothing?

```
MATCH path1 = (p1:PEOPLE)--(product:PRODUCT)--(p2:PEOPLE) 
WHERE p1.person_id <> p2.person_id
WITH path1,p1,p2
MATCH path2=(p1)--(:PRODUCT)--(p2) WHERE nodes(path2)<>nodes(path1)
WITH path1,path2,p1,p2
MATCH path3 = (p1)--(:PRODUCT)--(p2)
WHERE nodes(path3)<>nodes(path2) and nodes(path3)<>nodes(path1)
create (p1)-[:LINK]->(p2)
create (p2)-[:LINK]->(p1)
```

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `MATCH` clauses, use the [`count` aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-count) to check the number of common products between two nodes.

```
MATCH (p1:PEOPLE)--(product:PRODUCT)--(p2:PEOPLE) 
WITH p1, p2, count(product) AS commonProductCount
WHERE commonProductCount >= 3
CREATE (p1)-[:LINK]->(p2)
CREATE (p2)-[:LINK]->(p1)
```

**Note.** As a rule of thumb, there is no point creating two `LINK` relationships in the opposite directions. You should pick a single direction and create the relationship, and use undirected relatioships such as `()-[:LINK]-()` in your queries.